# Ionic1 + input [type=file] não funciona; Como faz para funcionar?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, html5, ionic

No meu projeto, tem um input do tipo file que no chrome funciona corretamente, no Ios não testei e no Android o input não funciona.

Existe algum plugin do Cordova que faça o input file funcionar ou alguma solução no javascript que funcione?

Answer (score 0):

Depende do tipo de arquivos que deseja permitir ao usuário escolher.

O `input type='file'` deve funcionar para o iOS, mas apenas permite escolher imagens da galeria do usuário. Já para o Android, só com o plugin-camera do Cordova (ele permite que o usuário acesse sua galeria de imagens).

A documentação do plugin-camera está [aqui](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/).

No entanto, se deseja permitir ao usuário selecionar qualquer tipo de arquivo, o plugin-file do Cordova (cuja documentação localiza-se [aqui](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/)) deve servir.